# seaborn.heatmap skips data

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, seaborn

When creating a heatmap via seaborn `seaborn==0.7.0.dev0`
my axis starts two hours later.
The DataFrame used to create the heatmap starts at:

`2015-05-19 21:10:00`

The first get_xticklabels of the heatmap created via seaborn however is `2015-05-19 23:10:00`.

The heatmap is created via

`sns.heatmap(df_test.T, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, ax=ax)`

What am I missing here?
This example (using seaborn 0.7 and 0.6) will start one hour later, in my real data it is even 2 hours.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=60*60*12, freq='s')


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(index)), index=index),
                   'b': pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(index)), index=index)})

#create boolean vars
df.a = df.a > 0
df.b = df.b > 0

df = df.resample('1Min', how=np.mean)

ax = plt.gca()
fig = plt.gcf()


sns.heatmap(df.T, ax=ax)

#print index
print df.index[0]

#print first xlabel
print ax.get_xticklabels()[0]

[label.set_visible(False) for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[1:]]
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

This will result in the following output

```
user@debian:/tmp$ python test.py 
2000-01-01 00:00:00
Text(0.5,0,u'2000-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100')
```

Comment: Can you post raw input data and code to reproduce this, thanks

Comment: What version of Seaborn are you using? Try updating to the latest 0.6.0.

Comment: I use seaborn==0.7.0.dev0

Comment: @Fiabetto does it run correctly with 0.6.0?

Comment: 0.6.0 doesn't work either

Comment: I get https://i.imgur.com/wYBKqn8.png  --  are you running the EXACT code that you posted exactly as posted?

Comment: @MikeGraham I get http://i.imgur.com/bta7sYr.png with the code from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay turns out it is the missing tz= value when creating the index which gives the offset inb the example code.

My solution (as changing tz in my DataFrame did not change this behaviour) was to set `xticklabel=False` in `heatmap()` and use `plt.xticks()` directly.